# Update a value in a column in Parse class

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to update a column in the class "currentUploads" in Parse:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3kRF.png)

This is what I am trying

```
@IBAction func reportButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Report Button Pressed")
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(buttonPosition)

    var alertMessage = NSString(format: "*User: %@\r *Text: %@\r *Created at %@", imageUploader[indexPath!.row], imageText[indexPath!.row]/*, imageCreated[indexPath!.row]*/)

    var reportAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Report Content", message:alertMessage as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    reportAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        println("Handle Report Logic here")
        self.reportContent()
    }))

    reportAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
    }))

    presentViewController(reportAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func reportContent(){
    let someQuery = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
    someQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("imageFile") {
        (updatedObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let updatedObject = updatedObject {
            updatedObject["reportedCount"] = "1"
            updatedObject.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to update/increment the "reportedCount" to 1 for the selected image in the `func reportContent`, but I get this error:

> [Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.8.0)
>   Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "No results matched the query."
>   UserInfo=0x7fae8a484aa0 {error=No results matched the query.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=No results matched the query., code=101})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because you a querying all the instances with "imageFile" in them, not the actual row. You want to use something like

```
someQuery.whereKey(objectId, EqualTo: objectId)
```

and use

```
someQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
```

where objectId would be the object ID of the object that you want to change the reportedCount of.

then you could do

```
object.setValue(object["reportedCount"] as! Int + 1, forKey: "reportedCount")
```

This is all psuedo code, but it is what I did to increment the number of friends my user had when they added a new friend.

Comment: Did i do something wrong? - http://s30.postimg.org/rkjj17erl/Screen_Shot_2015_10_19_at_19_11_51.png